# Find and delete files with linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I want to delete all files containing "chrome".
I have this command on linux :

```
    find . -type f -name '' -print -delete
```

after name I don't know what to put.

```
I tried *chrome* or *chrome*.*
```

Anyone know how to do it ?
thank you

Comment: "all files containing `chrome`" – Usually "a file containing `foo`" means `foo` can be found *inside* the file, something you can verify with `grep foo`. But `-name` in `find` tests *names* of files, not their content. Do you want to find `chrome` in files or in their names then?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to enclose the pattern in quotes in order to protect it from expansion by the shell, like below. Run it without the delete first to verify it lists the correct files for you:

```sh
# find and delete all files with 'chrome' in the name
find . -type f -name '*chrome*' # -print -delete
```

Comment: Good point about *testing* before deleting... now and then there are questions on StackExchange about what to do after essential system files have been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to delete all files containing "chrome"

This is ambiguous - either you mean file *names* containing `chrome` or you mean files whose *content* includes `chrome`. Let's consider both options here

1. File *names* containing `chrome`

   Typically you would specify a starting directory for the check. If you don't specify one, you are most likely to see that it will start in the current directory. Here, I've assumed it's the current directory so I have stated `.`:

   - Testing: `find . -type f -name '*chrome*' -print`
   - Actual: `find . -type f -name '*chrome*' -print -delete`

   You can make the delete variant remove files quietly by removing the `-print` option. You can omit the constraint to consider only *regular files* by removing `-type f`.

   This is case-sensitive - it will match `shiny chrome bumper` but not `Shiny Chrome Bumper`. You can replace `-name` with `-iname` for a case-insensitive variant.
2. Files whose *content* includes `chrome`

   Here I've also specified `.` so that the `find` command starts from the current directory:

   - Testing: `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do grep -l chrome "$f"; done' _ {} +` or simply `grep -rl chrome .`
   - Actual: `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do grep -l chrome "$f" && rm -f -- "$f"; done' _ {} +`

   You can make the deletion variant act quietly by changing `grep -l` to `grep -q`. You can make it case-insensitive with either `grep -il` or `grep -iq`.